# What happens if a C# Dictionary has a 64-bit TKey on x86?

Tags: c#, dictionary, hashtable

I'm reworking a few container classes from an old project of mine with (much more reusable) generic equivalents. I seem to have went *out of my way* years ago to ensure the `TKey` type for `Dictionary` was an `int` rather than my container's `T` type (which in this case, `T` is `long`).

If I rewrite this to allow `long` to be used, what actually happens under-the-hood in the `Dictionary` class? Will it just forcefully hashcode the 64-bit value-type `TKey` into a 32-bit int? Perhaps something like this:

```
int hashKey32bit = tkey.GetHashCode();
```

Comment: It just calls `tkey.GetHashCode()` - no casting to `object` is needed since `GetHashCode()` is already a member of all possible types. Anyway, it should just work if you change the key to `long`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson oh oops, you're absolutely right; the boxing isn't needed, I'll edit that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetHashCode` method always returns a 32 bit `int`, no matter what type or system you call it on. Thats the point of it and I don't see anything forcefully there. After all, there is no problem with using any object or struct of any size as key. (If they have a somewhat useful implementation of `GetHashCode`.)

The dictionary will probably end up with some collisions, but as long as the hash codes are distributed evenly across the 32 bit range thats fine.

**Edit**

So yes, the dictionary always calls the `GetHashCode` method, even for `int`, where it's rather simple:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return this;
}
```

For `long` (`int64`) it looks like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return (int) this ^ (int) (this >> 32);
}
```